# How to remove backslash from my php string which i pass in json

Tags: php, json, magento

my output is look like

```
"output": "{\"tree-level:\"1,\"Parent-name:\" ,\"Customer-name:\"devtest devtest}{\"tree-level:\"2,\"Parent-name:\"devtest devtest,\"Customer-name:\"devtest1 devtest1}{\"tree-level:\"3,\"Parent-name:\"devtest1 devtest1,\"Customer-name:\"level of sub level2ofsub}{\"tree-level:\"2,\"Parent-name:\"devtest devtest,\"Customer-name:\"devtest1@gmail.com devtest1@gmail.com}{\"tree-level:\"1,\"Parent-name:\" ,\"Customer-name:\"dev test 01 dev test 01}{\"tree-level:\"1,\"Parent-name:\" ,\"Customer-name:\"Heydemo Heydemo}{\"tree-level:\"2,\"Parent-name:\"Heydemo Heydemo,\"Customer-name:\"heyhey heyhey}{\"tree-level:\"1,\"Parent-name:\" ,\"Customer-name:\"new Demo new demo}{\"tree-level:\"1,\"Parent-name:\" ,\"Customer-name:\"BHarat shah}{\"tree-level:\"1,\"Parent-name:\" ,\"Customer-name:\"Nehal Patel}{\"tree-level:\"1,\"Parent-name:\" ,\"Customer-name:\"jayesh shrimali}{\"tree-level:\"1,\"Parent-name:\" ,\"Customer-name:\"nnn ggg}{\"tree-level:\"1,\"Parent-name:\" ,\"Customer-name:\"test webkul}",
```

But i want it like

```
"output": [{"tree-level:"1,"Parent-name:" ,"Customer-name:"devtest devtest}{"tree-level:"2,"Parent-name:"devtest devtest,"Customer-name:"devtest1 devtest1}{"tree-level:"3,"Parent-name:"devtest1 devtest1,"Customer-name:"level of sub level2ofsub}{"tree-level:"2,"Parent-name:"devtest devtest,"Customer-name:"devtest1@gmail.com devtest1@gmail.com}{"tree-level:"1,"Parent-name:" ,"Customer-name:"dev test 01 dev test 01}{"tree-level:"1,"Parent-name:" ,"Customer-name:"Heydemo Heydemo}{"tree-level:"2,"Parent-name:"Heydemo Heydemo,"Customer-name:"heyhey heyhey}{"tree-level:"1,"Parent-name:" ,"Customer-name:"new Demo new demo}{"tree-level:"1,"Parent-name:" ,"Customer-name:"BHarat shah}{"tree-level:"1,"Parent-name:" ,"Customer-name:"Nehal Patel}{"tree-level:"1,"Parent-name:" ,"Customer-name:"jayesh shrimali}{"tree-level:"1,"Parent-name:" ,"Customer-name:"nnn ggg}{"tree-level:"1,"Parent-name:" ,"Customer-name:"test webkul}],
```

Comment: How do you generate the output?

Comment: This doesn't look like valid json. Reconsider how it is being generated.

Comment: i generate this output from my function .output is in php and i want to convert this in jason

Comment: If your function doesn't use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) then refactor it to use it.

Comment: Magento has `Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($array)`